# App services created using visual studio having different icons in azure web portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have two App services which I deployed to the same resource groups within the same region. The icon associated with them are different while both of them identify as App Service. Why are the icons different and what do they mean? Any cost implications?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure App Services come in different flavors including Web Apps, API Apps, Mobile Apps, and technically Function Apps (Azure Functions).  The first App Service in the above image is a Mobile App and the second is a standard Web App. They are all technically web apps but the Mobile and API apps offer some subtly different default configurations and features that target the specific needs of supporting mobile app back ends or hosting APIs for example.

You should ensure you're deploying to the desired app service type before continuing. Generally speaking you would know if you needed to deploy to a Mobile App so if this is by accident I would recreate the resource as a standard Web App App Service. More details available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview